How to set project name and context name in 'dotnet ef' command simultaneously for 'add migrations' command (.NET 8)
I execute this command
dotnet ef dbcontext -v info

And I get this answer:
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: No DbContext was found in assembly 'ef'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)

I don't know why dotnet tools can not find my EF definition, I have EF code in my project. But this is solution with a number of projects therefore I want to set exact project name and class name.
Command looks (in my opinion) as
dotnet ef --startup-project ../EF --context BillerEntities migration add init

However, this command doesn't work, unfortunately this is low quality program. I can not see no any errors or any warning what wrong in my command, just picture and meaningless message as result of execution of my command:
Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 8.0.10
Usage: dotnet ef [options] [command]
Options:
  --version        Show version information
  -h|--help        Show help information
  -v|--verbose     Show verbose output.
  --no-color       Don't colorize output.
  --prefix-output  Prefix output with level.
Commands:
  database    Commands to manage the database.
  dbcontext   Commands to manage DbContext types.
  migrations  Commands to manage migrations.
Use "dotnet ef [command] --help" for more information about a command.


Could you please try dotnet ef dbcontext -v info --project {project_name}? I shared my test result below. Pls correct me if I misunderstand your issue.

I had a test in my side, I have a solution which contains several projects, when I run command dotnet ef dbcontext -v info in the project folder, it could show me correct result of the DbContext I used in this project.

And when I run the command in the solution folder, I will get exception Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.CommandException: No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.

Therefore, I can use --project paramerter to define the project. The command is dotnet ef dbcontext -v info --project WebAppDefIdentity in my side.
The parameter --startup-project is used for setting relative path to the project folder of the startup project. Default value is the current folder. We can see detailed information here. I think the most simple way is running the application inside the project folder.
